# Correo de cpanel de hostgator llega a spam

Tags: hosting, email, cpanel, popup, smtp

Buen día, he dado mil vueltas con este problema, GoDaddy tenía un servicio llamado Workspace email el cual no corría en el cpanel si no en la cuenta de usuario pero tampoco era un correo comercial como lo ofrece Google con G-Suite por ejemplo el cual cuesta al rededor de 5 USD por cuenta, yo lo configuraba en el programa Outlook de office o bien por medio de Gmail "atando" el correo en una cuenta normal xxxx@gmail.com para que sea revisado via POP y enviado via SMTP, todo iba de maravilla y funcionaba super bien, este servicio dejó de prestarse en godaddy y cuando fui a necesitar comprar mas espacio para crear mas correos pues por lo dicho, no pude comprarlo asi que pregunte sobre la opción de los tales correos ilimitados que hay en el cPanel, ellos mismos me dijeron que no recomendaban crear los correos allí ya que no daban garantía, pregunté que en hostgator y me hablaron maravillas de su correo funcionando en cPanel y por ende les creí y lo compré, moví allí todas los dominios, paginas de wordpress, bases de datos y por supuesto cree las cuentas de correos en lo mas de 20 dominios que tenia en godaddy etc etc...

compré uno tipo shared según entiendo es compartido con otros usuarios en un mismo servidor, y resulta que todo funciona bien excepto cuando se envían correos ya que llegan a spam especialmente si el destinatario es xxxx@hotmail.com, he contactado soporte 10 veces o mas y me dicen que todo esta bien, que revisan SPF y otras cosas, que no coloque URLS en las firmas, que no use clientes como outlook o gmail via POP y SMTP si no por medio del webmail de ellos, en fin... he intentado mil cosas hasta que un agente despues de contarle todo esto me dijo que quizá era por que estaba en un shared plan y que si compraba una VPS se solucionaría ya que posiblemente hotmail detectaba que se enviaban demasiados correos de ese servidor compartido, les pregunto, vuelvo a creer? no puedo permitirme comprar GSuite ya que cuesta 5USD por mes por cuenta creada y en un dominio cualquiera puedo tener hasta 15 cuentas lo cual saldria muy costoso, para mi tiene sentido eso de que al estar en un shared hosting se envian muchos y por eso hotmail me pone los correos como spam, que me aconsejan?

Comment: te resolvieron tu problema? justo estoy en la misma situación y al parecer no es algo reciente, hay articulos de hace años que detallan ese problema, y justo lo que me atrajo fueron los correos, por otra parte aunque es logico que al ser un servicio compartido pueda haber algun problema, sin embargo revisando mi spam encontre correos xxxx@32.hostgator.mx por lo que imagino que ni ellos se salvan de esta situacion y pareciera que esta fuera de su alcance.

Comment: @AntonioAyala segun Hostgator, me dijeron que al ser un server compartido y salir muchos correos por ahi, hotmail detecta que es spam, que si adquiero una VPS, al ser dedicada pues no tendria ese problema por que solo saldria correos de mi parte